# Ruby system command with special characters

Tags: ruby, shell

I need to launch a system command with two specials characters inside

```
system "my command "#{$value command here}" other ARGS here"
```

i can't use directly

```
system "my command #{$value command here} other ARGS here"
```

I need to insert `"` character at the begining and the end of my value command.How i can do that using system ?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you're composing system commands you **must** do one of two things. Either escape the values using [`shellescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape) to be sure the shell parses them correctly:

```
require 'shellwords'
system "my command #{"$value command here".shellescape} other ARGS here"
```

Or you can split out the arguments separately so the shell doesn't need to interpret them:

```
system("my", "command", "$value command here", "other", "ARGS", "here")
```

The second form is usually better, everything's much more explicit and there's no chance of you forgetting to escape something.

Remember when running shell commands that contain user data can expose you to severe risk. You absolutely must escape anything and everything that's not fixed by you in advance to avoid a shell-level exploit. On top of that remember filenames can and will contain spaces, especially on files uploaded from Windows where `Untitled (1).rtf` is a very common name.

Comment: Thank you for the "The second form is usually better" part. The single argument form of `system` (and backticks for that matter) have caused so many problems.

Comment: I really like the ruby syntax, finaly i used your first code `require 'shellwords'
system "my command #{"$value command here".shellescape} other ARGS here"`

Comment: @flowdaguerre As we've pointed out, you really, really, really, really, really, *really* want to use the second form. I'm not kidding. Tiny mistakes can cost you huge. What you prefer only matters so much when security concerns are present.